# How to identify if my website DNS is A-Record or CNAME?

Tags: domain-name-system, web-hosting

I am really a novice in network terminologies.

Can you let me know how to identify if my existing website DNS is A-Record or CNAME?
I have access to the web-server, so I will be able to verify the configuration settings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The webserver has nothing to do with DNS, they are two totally separate systems.

The easiest way to tell is using nslookup, dig, or a website that does it for you.

[Here is a link to a website](http://www.dnswatch.info/), type the name in, the resulting report will tell say if it's a C-NAME or A Record.

Comment: can you tell me how to identify using nslookup approach?

Comment: run `nslookup`, enter the name. If the answer includes a "Aliases: whatever.example.com" line then the name you typed in is a c-name pointing to whatever appears on the "Name: " line. If there is only  "Name" and "Address" lines then it's an A record.